# How can I access Configuration::get('PS_LAST_QTIES') at core.js?

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, smarty

at prestashop 1.7 how could I access Configuration::get('PS_LAST_QTIES') at core.js?

Thank you,
Miguel Gibert

Comment: You can define variable at head template and set configuration value there then use that variable in core.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted it out by passing the variable through the `ProductController.php`

at `$this->ajaxRender(Tools::jsonEncode([`

I added: `'ps_last_qties' => Configuration::get('PS_LAST_QTIES')`

and then I received it at core.js: `o.default.on("updatedProduct", function (e) {`

and was able to use it as `e.ps_last_qties`